# Formula to save seconds and Milliseconds in Sharepoint List for DateTime type column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splistitem

is there any way to hold datetime with seconds and milliseconds in sharepoint list where column type is 'DateTime'.

currently my list column saving as below
1/9/2014 6:30 PM

but i need to show it as
1/9/2014 6:30:25:850 PM

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at database Wss_ContentXXX to table dbo.AllUserData in fields tp_Modified and tp_Created milliseconds always equals to 000.
For seconds you can use the following formula with a calculated field:

```
=TEXT(Created,"dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS")
```